# What anime and manga series need more questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

**Related: [Are there animes/mangas we want more questions for?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/274)**

The above question was related to what we should do about skewed tags and whether there were specific tags we wanted questions for. But it really didn't gather much in the way of a list; [one answer](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/357/274) came close, but it is limited, and difficult for us to still use that after so long.

So, in order to give an idea to users who want to help generate new and interesting content: What anime or manga series do we want more questions and content about?

Answer (score 5):

This is a list of several anime and manga series which have either not been asked about or need more questions. Feel free to strikeout/remove from this list as questions are asked and tags are created (or add *fresh, popular series which are not getting enough attention*):

- [*Blue Exorcist*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Exorcist)
- [*Princess Mononoke*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Mononoke)
- [*Baccano!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccano!)
- [*Future Diary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Diary)
- [*5 Centimeters Per Second*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Centimeters_Per_Second)
- [*Rosario + Vampire*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosario_%2B_Vampire)
- [*Welcome to the N.H.K.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_to_the_N.H.K.)
- [*Another*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_%28novel%29)
- [*School Days*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_Days_%28visual_novel%29)
- [*Air*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_%28visual_novel%29)
- [*Azumanga Daioh*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azumanga_Daioh)
- [*Baka and Test*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baka_and_Test)
- [*Love★Com*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Com)
- [*Love Hina*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Hina)
- [*School Rumble*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_Rumble)
- [*My Neighbor Totoro*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonari_no_Totoro)
- [*Air Gear*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Gear)
- [*Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_VII%3a_Advent_Children)
- [*Kanon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanon)
- [*Is This a Zombie?*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_This_a_Zombie%3F)
- [*Chrono Crusade*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrono_Crusade)
- [*Devil May Cry*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_May_Cry%3a_The_Animated_Series)
- [*Serial Experiments Lain*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Experiments_Lain)
- [*ChäoS;HEAd*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos;Head)
- [*Nana*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nana_%28manga%29)
- [*Shuffle!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffle!)
- [*Special A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_%C2%B7_A%3a_Special_A)
- [*Black★Rock Shooter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Rock_Shooter)
- [*Hyōka*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hy%C5%8Dka)
- [*Summer Wars*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Wars)
- [*Black Cat*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Cat_%28manga%29)
- [*Rozen Maiden*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rozen_Maiden)
- [*My Bride is a Mermaid*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Bride_is_a_Mermaid)
- [*Natsume's Book of Friends*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natsume%27s_Book_of_Friends)
- [*BECK*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beck_%28manga%29)
- [*Tonari no Kaibutsu-kun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonari_no_Kaibutsu-kun)
- [*Shaman King*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaman_King)
- [*Berserk*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserk_%28manga%29)
- [*Arakawa Under the Bridge*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arakawa_Under_the_Bridge)
- [*Ga-Rei: Zero*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ga-rei)
- [*Love, Chunibyo & Other Delusions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love,_Chunibyo_%26_Other_Delusions)
- [*Demon King Daimao*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_King_Daimao)
- [*Heaven's Lost Property*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven%27s_Lost_Property)
- [*IS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IS_%28Infinite_Stratos%29)
- [*B Gata H Kei*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_Gata_H_Kei_Yamada%E2%80%99s_First_Time)
- [*Kara no Kyōkai*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kara_no_Ky%C5%8Dkai)
- [*Digimon Adventure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure)
- [*Laputa: Castle in the Sky*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky)
- [*Working!!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working!!)
- [*Grave of the Fireflies*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_of_the_Fireflies)
- [*Umineko: When They Cry*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umineko%3a_When_They_Cry)
- [*Bludgeoning Angel Dokuro-Chan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bludgeoning_Angel_Dokuro-Chan)
- [*Hetalia: Axis Powers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetalia%3a_Axis_Powers)
- [*Nyan Koi!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyan_Koi!)
- [*Sekirei*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sekirei)
- [*Kiss×sis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissxsis)
- [*Honey and Clover*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_and_Clover)
- [*Seitokai Yakuindomo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seitokai_Yakuindomo)
- [*Bunny Drop*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunny_Drop)
- [*Kämpfer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4mpfer)
- [*07-Ghost*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/07-Ghost)
- [*Kiki's Delivery Service*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiki%27s_Delivery_Service)
- [*K*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_%28anime%29)
- [*Sankarea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankarea)
- [*Canaan*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canaan_%28anime%29)
- [*Maria†Holic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Holic)
- [*Shugo Chara!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shugo_Chara!)
- [*Minami-ke*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minami-ke)
- [*Nabari no Ou*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabari_no_Ou)
- [*Itazura na Kiss*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itazura_na_Kiss)
- [*Ah! My Goddess*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ah!_My_Goddess)
- [*Romeo x Juliet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_x_Juliet)
- [*My-HiME*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mai-HiME)
- [*My-Otome*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My-Otome)
- [*Kyoushirou to Towa no Sora*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyoushirou_to_Towa_no_Sora)
- [*Steel Angel Kurumi*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Angel_Kurumi)

Comment: Note that this list was complied from the top MAL entries sorted by popularity and removing duplicates and entries we already have.

Comment: I've started asking questions from some of these, but the problem is, nobody answers them.

Comment: @kuwaly What I'd do if I were you is keep a certain number "open" at a time. So, if you ask 3 questions from series that aren't getting a lot of attention, then don't ask any for a bit (though ones on *Naruto* and stuff would still be fine). Then, as one of the old questions gets answered, you ask a new one.

Comment: I added My-Hime and My-Otome separately, but My-Otome is a spin-off, so we can possibly put them together. There are also a number of series that have tags but no questions. Do we want them on this list or a separate list for them?

Comment: @kuwaly This list will be fine for those as well.

Comment: I will actually amend what I just said--there are a number of series with one question. Should we look for more questions for those or leave them be for right now?

Comment: @kuwaly I think the main point of this was to have tags for all the commonly watched series. While you should still ask questions for those if you think of good ones, I don't think it's as important.

Answer (score 3):

On ANN:

- [Top 50 anime, best rated](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/ratings-anime.php?top50=best_bayesian), highest rating using bayesian estimate
- [Top 50 anime, most viewed](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/ratings-anime.php?top50=most_viewed), highest number of votes (good or bad)
- [Top 50 manga, best rated](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/ratings-manga.php?top50=best_bayesian)
- [Top 50 manga, most viewed](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/ratings-manga.php?top50=most_viewed)

Combining these 4 lists, removing duplicates, and removing what we already have tagged, we get:

- 20th/21st Century Boys
- 5 Centimeters Per Second
- A Bride's Story
- Absolute Boyfriend
- Air Gear
- Alice 19th
- Angel Sanctuary
- Ao Haru Ride
- Azumanga Daioh
- Baccano!
- Berserk
- Blade of the Immortal
- Buddha
- Bunny Drop
- Cardcaptor Sakura
- Ceres: Celestial Legend
- Children of the Sea
- Claymore
- Cross Game
- D.N.Angel
- Dengeki Daisy
- FLCL
- Final Fantasy VII: Advent Children
- Fruits Basket
- Full Metal Panic!
- Fushigi Yugi
- Glass no Kamen
- Grave of the Fireflies
- Gravitation
- Gurren Lagann
- Hana-Kimi
- Hellsing
- Historie
- Honey and Clover
- Kanon
- Kare Kano
- Kino's Journey
- Koori no Mamono no Monogatari
- Legend of the Galactic Heroes
- Lone Wolf and Cub
- Love Hina
- Magic Knight Rayearth
- Maison Ikkoku
- Maria Watches Over Us
- Message to Adolf
- Mononoke
- NANA
- Natsume's Book of Friends
- Nausica: of the Valley of the Wind
- Ode to Kirihito
- Oh My Goddess!
- Panorama of Hell
- Phoenix
- Pluto
- Princess Mononoke
- REAL
- Saiyuki Gaiden
- Sakura-Gari
- Sanctuary
- Shaman King
- Solanin
- Stigma
- Summer Wars
- Betrayal Knows My Name
- Garden of Sinners (Kara no Kyoukai)
- The Girl Who Leapt Through Time
- The Heart of Thomas
- The World is Mine
- Town of Evening Calm, Country of Cherry Blossoms
- Twin Spica
- Vagabond
- Vinland Saga
- Wandering Son
- With the Light: Raising an Autistic Child
- Wolf's Rain
- Yokohama Kaidashi Kikou
- Yotsuba&!